# Are these inherited properties?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I am learning about inherited properties and I am pretty confused. I would really appreciate your help to give me some clarity.

So, an inherited property is a property that the object inherits from the prototype object.

An article I read gave an example of an inherited property: "every JavaScript object inherits the toString property from its prototype object"

So, my question is:
Are these all inherited properties?

- **Static methods**

  Object.assign()

  Object.create()

  Object.defineProperty()

  Object.defineProperties()

  Object.entries()

  Object.freeze()

  Object.fromEntries()

  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()

  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames()

  Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()

  Object.getPrototypeOf()

  Object.is()

  Object.isExtensible()

  Object.isFrozen()

  Object.isSealed()

  Object.keys()

  Object.preventExtensions()

  Object.seal()

  Object.setPrototypeOf()

  Object.values()

  **Instance properties**

  Object.prototype.constructor

  Object.prototype.**proto**

  **Instance methods**

  Object.prototype.**defineGetter**()

  Object.prototype.**defineSetter**()

  Object.prototype.**lookupGetter**()

  Object.prototype.**lookupSetter**()

  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()

  Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()

  Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable()

  Object.prototype.toLocaleString()

  Object.prototype.toString()

  Object.prototype.valueOf()

(I found this list from MDN objects, they are static methods, instance properties, and instance methods of objects, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

And So, does that mean all objects have the above properties?

And since functions are basically objects, functions also inherited those?

Also, is there a place I can find the list of all the inherited properties objects have?

Thank you so much in advance! sorry for the long post.

Comment: You're on the right track. I recommend Javascript, the Good Parts, by Douglas Crockford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *static methods*, belong only to the `Object` class ( constructor function ), that means that you can call them only by doing `Object.nameOfMethod()`.

The *instance properties & methods* on the other hand, are inherited by all the instances of Object, which means that every object will inherit those props/methods.

Now remember that in JS every entity if it's not a primitive, is an object.

For example an array:

```
const arr = ["hello"]

console.log(typeof arr)                           // object
console.log(arr instanceof Object)                // true
console.log(Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(arr))   // true
console.log(arr.propertyIsEnumerable(0))          // true
console.log(arr.toLocaleString())                 // hello
console.log(arr.valueOf())                        // ["hello"]
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty(0))                // true
console.log(arr.toString())                       // hello
```

This is because even if *arrays* in JS are instances of `Array`, they are also instances of `Object`, you can see an array as a special object where indexes are keys:

```
const arr = {
0: "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static methods cannot be inherited, because they exist on the class and not on any instance of a class. So those are out. The other methods, absolutely! At least I think so. Let's run some experiments and check the results.

```js
const f = () => {
    return "hello world"
};
f.foo = "bar";

console.log(f.constructor);
console.log(f.toString());
console.log(f.valueOf());
console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("foo"));
console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("frankincense"));
```

This snippet indicates that, yes indeed, non-static methods are inherited by functions, because functions are objects... as Crockford rolls in his grave

Comment: Thank you for the amazing explanation! Really appreciate your help. Also, I found a pdf copy of the book you recommended online and it's exactly the book I needed.